# Context menu not appearing when selecting on empty area of listbox windows phone

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8, listbox, contextmenu

In my windows phone application I've a data bound list box. My data template contains many text blocks.

If I tap and hold on any of the text blocks, context menu appears. But if I tap and hold in the empty area of the listbox item the menu won't appear.

For example. If I select on any of the text area in the below mentioned image the menu appears. If I keep holding in the area between the name and date the menu is not appearing.

i want the menu to appear if I hold any where inside the particular list box item.

[image]

Note : I included the context menu

My xaml code goes as follows :

```
 <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border BorderThickness="0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25" BorderBrush="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                            <toolkit:ContextMenu >
                                <toolkit:MenuItem 
                                    Header="delete" 
                                    Click="Delete" />
                            </toolkit:ContextMenu>
                        </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>

                        <TextBlock 
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                            TextWrapping="NoWrap" 
                            Grid.Row="0" 
                            Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
                            Text="{Binding TEXT}" 
                            VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                            FontWeight="Bold"/>
                        <TextBlock 
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                            TextWrapping="NoWrap"
                            Grid.Row="1" 
                            Grid.Column="0" 
                            Text="{Binding USERNAME}" 
                            VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                            FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeSmall}"/>
                        <TextBlock 
                            HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                            TextWrapping="NoWrap" 
                            Grid.Row="1" 
                            Grid.Column="1" 
                            Text="{Binding Path=DATE}" 
                            VerticalAlignment="Top"
                            FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeSmall}" />
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

is there any way to solve this ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `Background="{StaticResource TransparentBrush}"` to the Grid in the DataTemplate.